# Concatenation of binding's path property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, path, concatenation

I have a question that is connected with setting path when binding in XAML, using WPF.

Imagine that my DataContext is of PropertyInfo type. PropertyInfo contains data about Property Name.

And in that object I nest (for example) TextBox which Text property I would like to bind to property with that name of another's element DataContext.

Something like that [it's pseudocode because it's not possible that way]:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Text={Binding ElementName=someElement, Path=DataContext. + {Binding Path=Name}}/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to create flexible view that's why I need to solve that problem.
Is there a way to achieve this without code behind?

Considering all the above, I think that I can make my question short and simply ask whether there is a way to concatenate string while setting binding's path.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly but is this something that multibinding would assist with?

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Padding="5"><TextBlock.Text>
<MultiBinding StringFormat="[{0}, {1}]">
            <Binding Path="LastName"></Binding>
            <Binding Path="FirstName"></Binding>
 </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Not really. Imagine that you have information about binding path stored in your DataContext and you want to set it, let's say, dynamically. Like in example. MultiBinding can be used in order to pass both object propertyInfo and datacontext but then It would be hard to do two way binding.

Comment: I understand but unfortunately don't know of a XAML-only way to do this. Binding to an interface and providing a variable concrete  implementation at runtime within your viewmodel might be a workable route.